# JavaScript & jQuery Function Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am making a generic text validation function with jQuery. I made the function text and I pass the id,requirement,expression,offset,limit into the function. The way I have made it is to help me run the function easily on single input change and on the submit of the whole form. I have made the function but I can't get it to run.

```
var Val = {
    'text' : function(event, ident,req,regexp,offset,limit) {
        var ele = $(document.getElementById(ident));

        if(req == 1 && ele.val().length < 1) {
            Val.errors = true;
            $("#"+ident+"Error").html("Please enter your " + ele.attr("title"));
            $("#"+ident+"Error").show("fast");
        } else if(ele.val().length <= offset || ele.val().length > limit) {
            Val.errors = true;
            $("#"+ident+"Error").html(ele.attr("title") + " should be between " +offset+ " & " +limit+ " charecters long");
            $("#"+ident+"Error").show("fast");
        } else if(regexp != null) {
            switch (regexp) {
                case 'text':
                    var regEx = /^([a-zA-Z]+)$/; break;
                case 'number':
                    var regEx = /^([0-9]+)$/; break;
                case 'email':
                    var regEx = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/; break;
                case 'date':
                    var regEx = /^([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})$/; break;
                case 'alphanum':
                    var regEx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$/; break;
                default:
                    var regEx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$/; break;
            }
            if(!regEx.test(ele.val())) {
                Val.errors = true;
                $("#"+ident+"Error").html(ele.attr("title") + " is not valid");
                $("#"+ident+"Error").show("fast");
            }
        }
    },

    'send' : function (){
        if(!Val.errors) {
            $('#form').submit();
        }
    }
}
```

The calling code of the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send').click(function(){
        Val.text('test', 1, 'email', 10, 50);
        Val.send(); 
    });

    $('#test').bind('change', Val.text);
    $('#test').trigger('change', ['test', 1, 'email', 10, 50]);
});
```

I know I haven't yet used the expressions but I will once I see it working.

Appreciate all the help...

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you can't get it to run, what exactly is happending?

Comment: Nothing! Can you see anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work. Once the script worked properly no trigger was required. I was able to just call simply inside the change event.

```
$('#emailID').change(function(){
    Val.text('emailID', 1, 'email', 10, 100);
});
```

Thanks everyone for the help anyway.